# <p> elements follow a range <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a comparative map [using mapbox.js](http://raphi.m0le.net/data/BAS/analyse%20chute%20bastion%20ries/carte-ecartrk.html).

The special thing is that I used a range input to show or hide the two layers. I also put above my map two paragraphs elements, to introduce basically the year of reference of each layer.

[image: The map with the p elements above]

What I wanted to do seems to be simple but I didn't achieve it. I would that the paragraphs elements strictly follow the range once loaded. For example, if I put  the range to the right of the map, I would have the "2014" text completely hidden.

Does someone know if that's posible ?

Here's the HTML canvas :

```
  <p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:2.4em; position:absolute; top:-30px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:75px; color:#cbcfcf;  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px black">2008</p>

 <p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:2.4em; position:absolute; top:-30px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:335px; color:#f3f4f4;  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px black">2014</p>

<div id='map'>
  <input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="1.0" step="any" />
</div>
```

And here's the Javascript :

```
// I start with all my variables
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '',{zoomControl: false});

var myGridLayer = L.mapbox.gridLayer('raphadasilva.6401kyb9').addTo(map);

var myGridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(myGridLayer).addTo(map);

L.mapbox.tileLayer('raphadasilva.e77ousor').addTo(map);

var overlay = L.mapbox.tileLayer('raphadasilva.0ri9t3xr').addTo(map);

var range = document.getElementById('range');

// here's the important function to show or hide a layer :

function clip() {
    var nw = map.containerPointToLayerPoint([0, 0]),
        se = map.containerPointToLayerPoint(map.getSize()),
        clipX = nw.x + (se.x - nw.x) * range.value;

    overlay.getContainer().style.clip = 'rect(' + [nw.y, clipX, se.y, nw.x].join('px,') + 'px)';
}

range['oninput' in range ? 'oninput' : 'onchange'] = clip;
map.on('move', clip);
```

Comment: The simplest solution might be to make those map images about 50 pixels taller, and put the numbers 2008 and 2014 into the map images, in that opened-up space at top.  Then they would just be another part of the overall images, of which one overlays the other per the range slider.  No separate paragraph-text needed.